# Mapbox - FLUTTER SDK

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android, mapbox-ios

I have gone through the mapbox documentation and come to know that it provides offline support for both Android and IOS.

My requirement is to use direction functionality offline. Since We can download and store particular region, Can we load direction between two points?

Is mapbox provode such functionality. I have gone through the mapbox documentation and come to know about offline map features but is there any way to integrate offline direction using Mapbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direction is an ML-generated route API that is only accessible through the internet. Only `100,000` requests are free per month to use this service for free. To access the API you are required to use something like

```
https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/-122.42,37.78;-77.03,38.91?access_token=YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Read more about [Mapbox offline](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/mobile-offline/), [Mapbox directions](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/directions/)

Comment: Please add the reference url in answer if possible. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can we use direction on download or saved map being online ?

Comment: Yes, you can use directions with saved maps. It's not directly related to Mapbox. You can use their directions service with any other map service too.

Comment: How? Can you please guide? Why you replied that direction can not be offline.?

Comment: Directions and Offline Map tiles are not directly related to each other these are both different things. In most cases you need a map to use directions but you don't need to use directions while using map only. So map is the basic feature and directions is a specific feature. As I mentioned in the answer that directions are ML generated service that takes time g worth to build. You cannot use mapbox directions offline but if you want offline feature you need to create a ML model which is trained on getting the right path from millions of latitudes & longitudes.

Comment: You can also check on Google Maps application that if you are offline you can not get Directions but you can use there maps offline

Comment: The documentation of Mapbox offline clearly states that you can only download map tiles for offline use

Comment: Thanks, Can you please share link that mention this ?

Comment: By the way, We just have to load the custom created style or Tile and have to draw path on it between two distance. Can you please guide about it ?